# 再変換を確定させるという意味のエンタキーのマクロはどのように書きますでしょうか？

Tags: emeditor

追記
リファレンスに書かれていましたのをわかってませんでした。質問でできないと書いてますが出来ます。
http://www.emeditor.org/ja/macro_shell_send_keys.html

再変換の質問の続きになります。
EmEditorで一行ずつ青い選択状態で下がっていくにはどのようにマクロで記述しますでしょうか？
document.selection.SelectAll();
editor.ExecuteCommandByID(4199);
画像はこのマクロをどうささせたとき、画像の所までは進みます。これで1行目の候補が出るところまではできるのですが

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
確定させるという意味のエンタキーのマクロはどのように書きますでしょうか？検索しても出ず、確定させるというコマンドがマクロでも記録されないです。
しかたないので他でエンタキーを押したときのマクロを記録して流用しようとすると
document.selection.NewLine(1);
この記録があるだけで、改行のときのエンターキーと再変換を確定させるためのエンタキーでは意味が違うので組み合わせてマクロを作ってもうまく動作しなかったです。
そのため画像のように行が下がって1行目だけで再変換の確定という動作が進まないので1行目の候補が出るだけで止まってしまいます。このときに確定させるコマンドは何になりますでしょうか？
それができた場合に、あとは繰り返しになるため、その後の最後の行までループさせる記述はありますでしょうか？
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

次のように記述してください。

```
editor.ExecuteCommandByID(4199);
shell.SendKeys( "~" );
```

ループの記述については、[こちらで回答しています](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/74959/emeditor%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AE%E3%83%AB%E3%83%BC%E3%83%97%E3%81%AE%E8%A8%98%E8%BF%B0%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A4%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6)。

Comment: ありがとうございます。確定できました。こちらに出していただいてました。http://www.emeditor.org/ja/macro_shell_send_keys.html　気がつきませんでしたのは「エンター」とカタカナ検索をしていました。英語表記でした。

Comment: お世話になっております。承認や評価が消失する問題が起きました。正当な質問と技術回答であったことを事務局に送っております。よろしくお願いいたします。