# EmEditorでのループの記述について

Tags: emeditor

お世話になっております。
この画像の最後の行まで再変換を繰り返すという方法です。
記述は一回で、あとは最後の行まで繰り返しと言う記述だと思います。
できれば、もとのひらがなは、●■マークで囲みをいれて変換後も前に残るようにしたいです

変換後は、
●おきなわ■沖縄
●かごしま■鹿児島

よろしくお願いいたします。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 0):

**2021/4/2 更新** - **EmEditor v20.6.905**以上では、`SendKeys` メソッドが改善されました。次のマクロを一度だけ実行してください。

**Reconvert.jsee**

```
document.selection.Replace("^.+?$","●\\0■\\0",eeFindReplaceCase | eeReplaceAll | eeFindReplaceRegExp,0);
document.selection.StartOfDocument(false);
while( document.selection.Find("(?<=■).+?$",eeFindNext | eeFindReplaceCase | eeFindReplaceRegExp,0) ) {
    editor.ExecuteCommandByID(4199);  // 再変換
    shell.SendKeys( "~" );
}
```

**EmEditor v20.6.904以前の場合**

<s>残念ながら、`SendKeys` メソッドは、マクロの途中で、現在実行中の EmEditor ウィンドウ自身あてには使用することができません。使用しようとすると、最後にまとめて実行されてしまいます。</s>

そこで、妥協案として、次の2つのマクロを使用されてはいかがでしょうか? 最初のマクロ `Reconvert1.jsee` では、まず `おきなわ` を `●おきなわ■おきなわ` というように、各行を `●` `■` で囲みをいれてコピーします。

2つめのマクロ `Reconvert2.jsee` では、カーソル位置の次の `■` の後の文字列を再変換して最初の候補で確定します。このマクロを行数分だけ繰り返して実行してください。

**Reconvert1.jsee**

```
document.selection.Replace("^.+?$","●\\0■\\0",eeFindReplaceCase | eeReplaceAll | eeFindReplaceRegExp,0);
document.selection.StartOfDocument(false);
```

**Reconvert2.jsee**

```
document.selection.Find("(?<=■).+?$",eeFindNext | eeFindReplaceCase | eeFindReplaceRegExp,0);
editor.ExecuteCommandByID(4199);  // 再変換
shell.SendKeys( "~" );
```

**Recovert1.jsee 実行後のサンプル**

```
●おきなわ■おきなわ
●かごしま■かごしま
●みやざき■みやざき
●くまもと■くまもと
●ふくおか■ふくおか
●おおいた■おおいた
●さが■さが
```

**Recovert2.jsee を7回実行後のサンプル**

```
●おきなわ■沖縄
●かごしま■鹿児島
●みやざき■宮崎
●くまもと■熊本
●ふくおか■福岡
●おおいた■大分
●さが■差が
```

Comment: 作成ありがとうございます。最後の行に来るまでボタンを押し続けること自体をマクロにできますでしょうか？よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: ＞残念ながら、SendKeys メソッドは、マクロの途中で、現在実行中の EmEditor ウィンドウ自身あてには使用することができません。

これはかなり問題のある仕様ではないでしょうか？その場合は今回のようにキー操作を途中でともなうマクロはつくれないということになりますでしょうか？これからキー操作も合間にともなうマクロを予定してますが、できない理由というのはは何になりますでしょうか？バージョンアップしていただけますでしょうか？よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 試行錯誤しまして、1回当たり、1行だけなら動くので、外部の別のマクロソフトでEmEditorの再生ボタンのホットキーをひたすら連打するという方法であれば最後の行まで繰り返し自動で押し続けることは可能なようですが、それだとEmEditor単体のマクロではないので設計としては妥協案でイマイチでした。EmEditor単体で最後の行まで連打ループの記述がありますでしょうか？よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: v20.6.905で改善し、回答を更新しました。

Comment: バージョンアップありがとうございます。最後まで出来ました。これは他のSendKeys メソッド全般が適材適所の動きが可能になったということになりますでしょうか？よろしくお願いいたします。